# Docker Compose - Entrypoint permission error (mariadb)

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-entrypoint

I have tried many things and searched for this it, but nobody seems to have my exact problem.

I installed docker on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using [these steps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-docker-engine) and the test run `docker run hello-world` works perfect.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 42
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./dbsetup
        target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The docker service is running and mariadb/adminer images download without error.

When I try to use `docker compose up` (sudo or not) I get the following error:

```
Attaching to dbexercise3-adminer-1, dbexercise3-db-1
dbexercise3-db-1       | 2022-11-26 01:01:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.10.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
dbexercise3-db-1       | 2022-11-26 01:01:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
dbexercise3-db-1       | 2022-11-26 01:01:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.10.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
dbexercise3-db-1       | ls: cannot open directory '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/': Permission denied
dbexercise3-adminer-1  | [Sat Nov 26 01:01:54 2022] PHP 7.4.33 Development Server (http://[::]:8080) started
dbexercise3-db-1 exited with code 2
```

Adminer starts as it should, however I can't log in (because the mariadb container doesn't exist).

I also tried installing Docker Desktop.
After I start the GUI application `docker compose up` works and I can work with the DB.
Of course I could simply use Docker Desktop and start it on boot, but I don't need the GUI and the need to manually update via DEB-package is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was surprisingly easy.

I simply hat to run `chmod 777 dbsetup` to clear the permission error.
I still have no idea how Docker Desktop managed to circumvent this issue, maybe because it runs a task which gives it higher priority?